# representing login in ER diagram

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm trying to develop a system, and doing the ER diagram now, i have two questions

1. I'm always thinking about the process and trying to do the ER, now i'm so confused i can't really think and do it, even though i have a knowledge in databases, how to over come this?
2. how to represent a login in the ER? please elaborate guys?

thanks in advance!

regards,
Rangana

Comment: "login" sounds like an action, which sounds like a workflow, which makes me think that an ER (Entity-Relation) diagram is not appropriate. Unless you mean there is a "login" entity, such as a username and password.

Comment: i have 4 type of uses, each one have their levels, so how can i represent them in my ER? how to store the login data and the levels of them? i'm giving them access to each part according to their level in the organisation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "login" itself can't be presented in the database. You mean users and their access, maybe their rights inside groups/ACL/...

In the most basic case, you would have a usertable with the login data

```
       user
---------------------
id            int
name          varchar
passwd        varchar
[ last_login  datetime
active        boolean
..... ]
```

Of course this is a simple example and needs to be adopted. So if you need more provileges, you could introduce a `is_admin (bool)` column. For more ACL stuff, you can create a `groups` table that stores the permissions and is connected to the user with a n:m relation.